# What game is in this video showing a green field with purple bushes and a 'No Power' message?

Tags: steam, game-identification

What game can be seen on this screenshot, and at 5s in the video?

[image: what game is this]

Answer (score 41):

The game is [Astroneer](https://astroneer.space/), a space sandbox and exploration game released on PC and XBOX. The game allows you to visit planets and exploit them to collect resources and craft different kinds of tools, modules and vehicles which will help you to travel and reshape the planets. You can recognize the [Organic](https://astroneer.gamepedia.com/Organic) symbol on the picture, which is one of the resources you can collect.